# How can I return to the previous edittext when the delete key is pressed?

Tags: java, android

[image: image1]

I have such an edittext layout. When a character is entered I want to go to the next edittext. When the delete button is pressed, I want to return to the previous edittext.

```
ArrayList<String> question = new ArrayList<>();
question.add("hello");
question.add("heyo");
question.add("Everyone");

for(int i = 0 ; i<array_edit_text.length ; i++ ){
        for(int j = 0 ; j<array_edit_text[i].size() ; j++){

            final int finalJ = j;
            final int finalI = i;
            array_edit_text[i].get(j).addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: If it's not necessary to use `EditText`, try this [Verification Code View](http://afra55.github.io/2016/12/22/verification_code_view/)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I used the CodeEditText library. The library's codes are here. https://github.com/lukelorusso/CodeEditText/tree/master/codeedittext/src/main   
when I try to create a new object of the class. She wants an attributeset from me, how can I give it.